# Nexus 7 2013 is permanently awake

Tags: nexus-7, wakelock

*Note: I do not mean screen-on state, but awake state.*

My Nexus 7 is permanently awake. It is not rooted, so I could not easily check for wakelocks. I did try the method to run [wakelock detector](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.uzumapps.wakelockdetector&hl=en) on a non-rooted device, however, and it started working for a moment, until I restarted Nexus. While it was working, it showed a 97% Awake state for a day or two of running.

However, the wakelocks were minimalistic. At first, there was [Any.do](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.anydo&hl=en) showing some good amount of holding awake state, but it was far from permanent wakelock. In a moment however the top 3 wakelock holders disappeared and only minimalistic wakelocks stayed. The minutes of awake state of the wakelocks shown would not add up nearly up to an hour of awake state, whereas the device was awake for more then 24 hours already.

Android system processes were shown too.

Do you know what could be causing a permanent awake state of the device? Can I do anything about it other than rooting the device? Towelroot is not working and I know of no other rooting method that would not leave my device flashed to the factory state (do not wanna lose state of the device).

Comment: not to pry but did you check you display settings. If that is OK then try to boot into safe mode and see if the problem persists. If yes then the OS is buggy or something is related to the OS of your nexus. If the answer is no for the safe mode then the problem definitely is because of some app.

Comment: Display settings? Just to clarify once again - the screen is off. The device appears off. This is not a display issue, but a CPU awake issue.

Comment: still the safe mode thing holds. Have you tried it